# getting a first even from a nested list of number from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help figuring out this code. This is my first programming class and we have a exam next week and I am trying to do the old exams.

There is one class with nested list that I am having trouble understanding. It basically says to convert `(list of [list of ints]) -> int`.

Basically given a list of list which ever has a even number in this case 0 is even return that index and if there are no even numbers we return -1.

Also we are given three examples

```
>>> first_even([[9, 1, 3], [2, 5, 7], [9, 9, 7, 2]])
1
>>> first_even([[1, 3, 5], [7, 9], [1, 0]])
2
>>> first_even([[1, 3, 5]])
-1
```

We are using python 3 in our class and I kind of have a idea in where to begin but I know its wrong. but ill give it a try

```
def first_even(L1):
    count = 0
    for i in range(L1):
       if L1[i] % 2 = 0:
           count += L1
    return count
```

I thought this was it but it didn't work out.

If you guys could please help me out with hints or solution to this it would be helpful to me.

Comment: +1 for giving it a try

Comment: Please say what did not work.  You got an error message related to `range(L1)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and you want to return the index of the first list that contains at least one even number:

```
In [1]: def first_even(nl):
   ...:     for i, l in enumerate(nl):
   ...:         if not all(x%2 for x in l):
   ...:             return i
   ...:     return -1
   ...: 

In [2]: first_even([[9, 1, 3], [2, 5, 7], [9, 9, 7, 2]])
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: first_even([[1, 3, 5], [7, 9], [1, 0]])
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: first_even([[1, 3, 5]])
Out[4]: -1
```

[`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a convenient built-in function that gives you both the index and the item if an iterable, and so you don't need to mess with the ugly `range(len(L1))` and indexing.

[`all`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) is another built-in. If all remainders are non-zero (and thus evaluate to `True`) then the list doesn't contain any even numbers.

Comment: I would argue that `any(x % 2 == 0 for x in l)` would be a bit more readable... (as it terms of what it's checking for)

Comment: @JonClements Maybe a little :) But you have to agree that this `all-to-any` conversion is trivial enough from the logical point of view.

Comment: More readable than `next((i for i, v in enumerate(a) if any(el % 2 == 0 for el in v)), -1)` anyway...

Comment: Nice and succinct code, but I think it's worth pointing out that range(len(x)) is generally used pretty commonly in introductory Python classes, so it's probably still good to be familiar with it.

Comment: @JonClements Thank God I didn't know `next` had a `default` argument :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor problems with your code:

- `L1[i] % 2 = 0` is using the wrong operator. `=` is for assigning variables a value, while `==` is used for equality.
- You probably meant `range(len(L1))`, as range expects an integer.
- Lastly, you're adding the whole list to the count, when you only wanted to add the index. This could be achieved with `.index()`, but this doesn't work for duplicates in the list. You can use `enumerate`, as I'm about to show below.

If you're ever working with indexes, `enumerate()` is your function:

```
def first_even(L):
    for x, y in enumerate(L):
        if any(z % 2 == 0 for z in y): # If any of the numbers in the subsists are even
            return x # Return the index. Function breaks
    return -1 # No even numbers found. Return -1
```

Comment: I dont understand your code, it doesnt satisfy the examples ?

Comment: Two more fixes for the existing code:

Since L1 is a list of lists, you need to iterate through each sublist. If you aren't using enumerate (although enumerate is great), the way to do this would be to have a loop such as "for j in range(len(L1[i]))." Within that inner loop, you can check if L1[i][j] % 2 == 0, and if it does you probably just want to return i. It seems like the count variable will just end up counting the number of even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I came up with.

```
def first_even(L1):
    for aList in range(len(L1)):
        for anItem in range(len(L1[aList])):
           if L1[aList][anItem] % 2 == 0:
               return aList
    return -1
```

First a fix. You need to use == for "equal to", '=' is for assigning variables.

```
L1[i] % 2 == 0
```

And for the code, here's the idea in some more pseudocodey style:

```
Iterate through the list of lists (L1):
    Iterate through the list's (aList) items (anItem):
        if List[current list][current item] is even:
            Return the current list's index
Return -1 at this point, because if the code gets this far, an even number isn't here.
```

Hope it helps, if you need any further explanation then I'll be happy to.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_even(L1):
    return ''.join('o' if all(n%2 for n in sl) else 'e' for sl in L1).find('e')
```